# PowerCLI: The metric counter "cpu.usagemhz.maximum" doesn't exist

Tags: powershell, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I am attempting to pull a variety of stats from each of our VMs on particular hosts. Everything works, except for the `$maxcpu` part.... I'm a PS noob, so I just tried to model it off of the other stats I pulled stylewise, but changed the CPU counter to `.maximum` rather than `.average`. With my experimentation, I either get a blank entry in the CSV, or it crashes and gives an error of :

`The metric counter "cpu.usagemhz.maximum" doesn't exist for entity "XXXX"`.

```
foreach ($vmhost in $hosts) { 
    $vms = Get-VM -Location $vmhost
    $vmHost | echo
    foreach ($vm in $vms) {
        "    " + $vm | echo 
        $avgcpu = @{N="Cpu.UsageMhz.Average";E={[Math]::Round((($_ |Get-Stat -Stat cpu.usagemhz.average -Start (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) | Measure-Object Value -Average).Average),2)}}
        $maxcpu = @{N="Cpu.UsageMhz.Maximum";E={[Math]::Round((($_ |Get-Stat -Stat cpu.usagemhz.maximum -Start (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) | Measure-Object Value -Maximum).Maximum),2)}}
        $avgmem = @{N="Mem.Consumed.Average";E={[Math]::Round((($_ |Get-Stat -Stat mem.consumed.average -Start (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) | Measure-Object Value -Average).Average),2)/1000}}

        $vm | Select Host, Name, NumCpu, $avgcpu, $maxcpu, MemoryMB, $avgmem | Export-Csv -Append "somewhere\csv.csv"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old [documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk25pubs/ReferenceGuide/cpu.html) says cpu.usagemhz.max is available in statistics level 4. @user3290553, if that has changed with 5.5, feel free to explain how you came by that information.

Just in case it's any help, there's a record of some troubleshooting on a related issue [here](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2177573).

*edit* - Here's a [5.5 reference](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/cpu_counters.html). The `(4)` in the Level column seems to mean that cpu.usagemhz.max is available in stat level 4. To check your stat levels in the thick/C#/non-web VC client, look under vCenter Server Settings > Statistics.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry I must have been looking at wrong documentation or made a mistake. So, I checked the statistics level and we only use `1` everywhere, thus we're missing all of the advanced statistics, such as `cpu.usagemhz.maximum`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that we are operating only vSphere 5.0, but the `.maximum` feature is available in 5.5.

Comment: Nevermind, I seem to have made a mistake, please instead look at the post by noam